# missing data using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to get the data of 
http://www.bbb.org/greater-san-francisco/business-reviews/architects/klopf-architecture-in-san-francisco-ca-152805

So I created some items to save the information, but I don't get all the data every time I run the script, usually I get some empty items so I need to run the script again until I get all the items.

This is the code of the spider

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import Product
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector



class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["bbb.org/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.bbb.org/greater-san-francisco/business-reviews/architects/klopf-architecture-in-san-francisco-ca-152805"
        #"http://www.bbb.org/greater-san-francisco/business-reviews/architects/a-d-architects-in-oakland-ca-133229"
        #"http://www.bbb.org/greater-san-francisco/business-reviews/architects/aecom-in-concord-ca-541360"
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        producto = Product()
        #producto['name'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="business-detail"]/div/h1')
        producto = Product(Name=response.xpath('//*[@id="business-detail"]/div/h1/text()').extract(),
        Telephone=response.xpath('//*[@id="business-detail"]/div/p/span[1]/text()').extract(),
        Address=response.xpath('//*[@id="business-detail"]/div/p/span[2]/span[1]/text()').extract(),
        Description=response.xpath('//*[@id="business-description"]/p[2]/text()').extract(),
        BBBAccreditation =response.xpath('//*[@id="business-accreditation-content"]/p[1]/text()').extract(),
        Complaints=response.xpath('//*[@id="complaint-sort-container"]/text()').extract(),
        Reviews=response.xpath('//*[@id="complaint-sort-container"]/p/text()').extract(),
        WebPage=response.xpath('//*[@id="business-detail"]/div/p/span[3]/a/text()').extract(),
        Rating = response.xpath('//*[@id="accedited-rating"]/img/text()').extract(),
        ServiceArea = response.xpath('//*[@id="business-additional-info-text"]/span[4]/p/text()').extract(),
        ReasonForRating = response.xpath('//*[@id="reason-rating-content"]/ul/li[1]/text()').extract(),
        NumberofEmployees = response.xpath('//*[@id="business-additional-info-text"]/p[8]/text()').extract(),
        LicenceNumber = response.xpath('//*[@id="business-additional-info-text"]/p[6]/text()').extract(),
        Contact = response.xpath('//*[@id="business-additional-info-text"]/span[3]/span/span[1]/text()').extract(),
        BBBFileOpened = response.xpath('//*[@id="business-additional-info-text"]/span[3]/span/span[1]/text()').extract(),
        BusinessStarted  = response.xpath('//*[@id="business-additional-info-text"]/span[3]/span/span[1]/text()').extract(),)



        #producto.add_xpath('name', '//*[@id="business-detail"]/div/h1')
        #product.add_value('name', 'today') # you can also use literal values
        #product.load_item()





        return producto
```

This page requieres to set an user agent, so I have a file of user agents, could be than some of them are wrong?

Comment: yes probably some of them are wrong, what happens if you just set `USER_AGENT="someuseragent"` on your settings (remember to remove the randoming useragent middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, some of your user agents could be wrong (maybe some old ones, deprecated) and the site, if there is no problem on using only one user-agent, you could add that to `settings.py`:

```
USER_AGENT="someuseragent"
```

Remember to remove or disable the randoming user-agent also from `settings.py`